# Como definir um padrão de exibição de casas decimais no R?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Estou com um script em rmarkdown que gera um relatório em .pdf.

Gostaria de padronizar a quantidade de casas decimais exibidas, sem precisar por o `round()` em toda função.

No começo do script, eu tentei utilizar:

```
options(scipen=30, digits=3)
```

Isso evita que os valores apareçam como notação científica, mas o número de casas decimais ainda esta variando. É possível criar esse padrão?

Comment: Eu sei que com `format(X, nsmall=3)` ele vai mostrar números como 1 e 1.5 como 1.000 e 1.500, mas não sei de uma opção global para isso.

Comment: *options(digits)* é considerado uma "sugestão"; qualquer função que especifique o número de casas para exibir algum resultado terá procedência. Se está gerando os documentos via Pandoc, dê uma espiada na função `pander::panderOptions`.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta obrigado! interessante essa library pander! Vai ajudar bastante!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível realizar isto para o *chunk* e para *inline*.

Veja no exemplo abaixo: o valor real, valor com modificação para *inline* e a modificação para o *chunk*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O code abaixo está em `rmd`, e consta de *head*, *print* valores originais (*chunk* 1), função para ajuste *inline* (*chunk* 2), ajuste para *print* de resultado (*chunk* 3) e *print* valores com padrão de casas decimais (*chunk* 4).

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
## R Markdown
```{r }
mean(mtcars$mpg)
pi
```
\
Valor de pi é igual a `r pi`.
\

## MOD - INLINE
```{r  , include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
inline_hook <- function (x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    res <- ifelse(x == round(x),
      sprintf("%d", x),
      sprintf("%.3f", x) # numero de casas decimais
    )
    paste(res, collapse = ", ")
  }
}
knit_hooks$set(inline = inline_hook)
```
\
Valor de pi é igual a `r pi`.
\

## MOD - CHUNK
```{r  , include=FALSE}
options(digits = 4)
```

```{r }
mean(mtcars$mpg)
pi
```
````

Fonte: [*inline*](http://www.jason-french.com/blog/2014/04/25/formatting-sweave-and-knitr-output-for-2-digits/).

Comment: Muito interessante essas funções! obrigado!